# Generating packages by schema with wsimport and JAX bindings ignores Service classes

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a WSDL with multiple schemas and i'm trying to get `wsimport` to generate code into packages of my choice by schema. Using the -b option with a JAX-WS/JAX-B bindings file i managed to basically do that.

Only two classes are still generated into the default path: the service interface and the service implementation.

With the -p option on the other hand all the classes are generated into one package, but when i use that all the bindings defined in the external file are ignored.

What is the XPath for the service so that `wsimport` will generate those files into my packages?
I tried things like

```
<jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:service"> ...
<jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:binding"> ...
<jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType"> ...
```

but neither had any effect.

Example:

```
<jaxws:bindings
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    wsdlLocation="myService.wsdl"
>

    <!-- this works for schemas -->
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://org.com/service/1.0']" >
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.myorg.service.v1" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxws:bindings>

    <!-- the following does nothing -->
    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:service">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.myorg.service.v1" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxws:bindings>

</jaxws:bindings>
```

Comment: What do you mean by “by schema”?  Aren’t the service interface and its implementation independent of the XML schemas?

Comment: The service is, but the used request/response objects are spread over different schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JAX-WS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxws-2_2a-mrel4-eval-spec/jaxws-2_2a-mrel4-eval-spec.pdf), section 8.4.1, you don’t need an XPath to specify a package for JAX-WS classes like the service and port classes:

```xml
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="http://example.org/foo.wsdl">
  <jaxws:package name="com.acme.foo"/>
```